# Remove ID from MVC URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, mvcroutehandler

I have a heref like this.

```html
 <a style="background: #3DB39E; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; border: none; width: 60px;" class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action("EditAccountUser", "Account", new { id = item.UsersID })">Edit</a>
```

controller like this

```html
 public ActionResult EditAccountUser(long id=0)
        {
           Return View();
        }
```

Route Config like this

```html
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default",
               url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
```

it gives me this http://exmaple.com/Account/EditAccountUser/7

I just want to remove "7" from above URL?

How I can do this?

Please let me know.

Thanks,

Vivek

Comment: What you mean by "I just want to remove "7" from above URL"? Your `id` part of route is optional.

Comment: make a POST request from JQuery AJAX, instead of GET.

Comment: HI ALL, THANKS FOR YOUR REPLY. I DO NOT WANT TO SHOW ID ON URL.

Answer (score 1):

try to refer this might help you [link](http://erraticdev.blogspot.in/2011/03/removing-route-values-from-linksurls-in.html)

or simply use url mapping in web.config

```
<urlMappings enabled="true">
  <add url="~/somedirectory/" mappedUrl="~/somedirectory/1/"/>
</urlMappings>
```

Comment: Hi Vijay,any other way like using [route] on the controller to hide route values.?

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "vijay.aspx",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
Probably this will not work but I am not sure about this sorry. try and comment if work. :D

Comment: then ala bachay meri jaan :p go with old ans friend. :D